# Cannot locate software (gnuplot) in drive or synaptic but showing in terminal

Tags: 12.04

I installed gnuplot 4.4.3 using the command '`sudo apt-get install gnuplot`'. It was working well. Later I tried to upgrade it to 4.6 version by '`sudo upgrade gnuplot`' but it didnt work. I downloaded some files from internet and using one of them I saw that the version name was coming 4.6.4. But the plot was not coming. I installed x11 terminal but it didnt work. I then uninstalled all gnuplot things using synaptic but still on command gnuplot in terminal, the version 4.6.4 is opening.

Reinstalling 4.4.2 is also not working.

How can I remove that gnuplot 4.6.2, not showing in any drive or software manager or synaptic?

Is there any directory analogous to 'Program files' in windows?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the command `which` to see where a command is, e.g. `which octave` may return `/usr/bin/octave`--- there isn't unified directory that's equivalent to Program Files, but depending on the kind of program and how it was installed, you may want `/bin`, `/usr/bin`, or `/usr/local/bin`, among others.